# Transform and transition not working in iOS Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, transform, mobile-safari

I did a simple page to display short messages on a "card" div element when the user clicks on that div. I researched and found CSS classes to use to make the div look like it's flipping from front to back when the user clicks. Pretty simple: the front of the card says "Click me", you click it, the card flips around and displays a message I defined in a string array in JS. You click again and the card flips back over to the front and again displays "Click me". The problem is I just learned that although it works fine in all my Windows browsers and Android browsers, it does NOT work in Safari on iOS. Specifically...

After clicking the card front, after the flip, the text in the messages seems to randomly display **backwards**(??). Also...again, not all the time...sometimes instead of waiting for the click/tap on the card to flip back to the front, Safari quickly flips it back over on its own, without waiting. Totally wrong.

Examples:

```
<style>
body {
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        background: lavenderblush;
    }

    .scene {
        width: 200px;
        height: 260px;
        margin: 40px 0;
        perspective: 600px;

    }

    .card {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
        transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background:white;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
    }

    .card.is-flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .card__face {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }

    .card__face--front {
        background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height:100%;
    }

    .card__face--back {
        background: lightskyblue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        word-wrap: normal;
        line-height: 260px;
        height:100%;
        display: inline-block; 
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #message {
        line-height: 1.5;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

</style>
```

The flipping effect is done with transform, transition, and transform-style classes, so I figured those weren't properly supported in iOS Safari, so I added -webkit-transform, -webkit-transition, and -webkit-transform-style classes for each of those...but it's still broken when I test it in BrowserStack (I don't own a Mac or iOS device). I made a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ziggy_zaggy/pen/qBBzBdg).

HTML:

```
<div class="scene scene--card">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__face card__face--front">
            <span>Click Me!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card__face card__face--back">
            <p id="message"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var card = document.querySelector('.card');
var counter = 0;

var messages = [
    "Hello",
    "world",
    "How",
    "are",
    "you?"
];

card.addEventListener('click', function () {

    var whichCard = card.classList.value;
    if (whichCard == "card") {
        getMessage();
    }

    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});

function getMessage() {
    //var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length); 
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[counter];
    incrementCounter();
}

function incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    if (counter >= messages.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Can someone please take a look and tell me what would make this break on iOS Safari (or maybe Safari on Mac desktop too? I don't know)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For some older versions of iOS you have to use prefixed properties for `transition` and `transform`. You should use something like this `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform`.

Comment: Um, didn't you read my post? I indicated that I already did that, but Safari still renders the transforms/transitions incorrectly.